# pandas find number order for respective column based on column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
df =
     0.5 -0.1
0   -0.3 -0.2
1   -0.1 -0.1
2    0.4  0.2
3    0.7  0.5
4    2.0  0.8
```

where I would like to get the rank of the column title, 0.5 and -0.1 in their respective columns based on the index number or in their order. This also would be nearest variable. The output would look something like this.

```
df1 = 
     0.5 -0.1
0      2    1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking for the first index in each sorted column where the value is greater than the column name? What have you tried so far, and what was your result? `filter`, `query`, `mask`, etc?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have tried to make the column names into a different dataframe and use pd.merge_asof but have had no luck

Comment: Again, need to clarify what is the logic? Why is the selection for the `.0.5` column the index for `0.4` value and not `0.7`? Is it the closest value or the smallest value over the column name?

Comment: You have already answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63403660/13676202) since you make almost the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the index of the closest value.

```
abs(df[col] - value).idxmin()
```

You can use it that way:

```
lst = []
for col in df.columns:
    lst.append( abs(df[col] - float(col)).idxmin() )
    
pd.DataFrame([lst],columns=df.columns)
```

[image]