# pandas find the nearest variables index from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorted DataFrame that looks like this,

```
df = 
       0      1
0   -0.3   -0.2
1   -0.1   -0.1
2    0.4    0.2
3    0.7    0.5
4    2.0    0.8
```

and another DataFrame that looks like this,

```
df1 = 
       0    1
0    0.5 -0.1
```

I would like the variables in `df1` to find their nearest respective value in `df` and write their index. The expected outlook would be something like this

```
df2 = 
       0    1
0    0.5 -0.1
1      2    1
```

Would some type of comprehensions work? Having a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: [REVIEW] Hi @Andrew, could you show the code you tried sofar ? Having trouble doesn't mean you're not on the right track with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `sub` and `idxmin`

```
s=df.sub(df1.values).abs().idxmin()
Out[38]: 
0    2
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of all, this will be two independent computations.  For a given value `x` in column 0 ...

- generate the vector `diff0` = abs(x - df["0"])
- locate (by index, `min0`) the value min(diff0)
- then insert df["0"] [row `min0`] into df2

Can you do the specific coding, now that you have a (relatively) simple algorithm?